# StreamReader is too greedy

Tags: c#, text, buffer, streamreader

I'm trying to process part of a text file, and write the remainder of the text file to a cloud blob using `UploadFromStream`.  The problem is that the StreamReader appears to be grabbing too much content from the underlying stream, and so the subsequent write does nothing.

Text file:

```
3
Col1,String
Col2,Integer
Col3,Boolean
abc,123,True
def,3456,False
ghijkl,532,True
mnop,1211,False
```

Code:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("c:\\test\\testinput.txt"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var numColumns = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
    while (numColumns-- > 0)
    {
        var colDescription = reader.ReadLine();
        // do stuff
    }

    // Write remaining contents to another file, for testing
    using (var destination = File.OpenWrite("c:\\test\\testoutput.txt"))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(destination);
        destination.Flush();
    }

    // Actual intended usage:
    // CloudBlockBlob blob = ...;
    // blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
}
```

When debugging, I observe that `stream.Position` jumps to the end of the file on the first call to `reader.ReadLine()`, which I don't expect.  I expected the stream to be advanced only as many positions as the reader needed to read some content.

I imagine that the stream reader is doing some buffering for performance reasons, but there doesn't seem to be a way to ask the reader where in the underlying stream it "really" is.  (If there was, I could manually `Seek` the stream to that position before `CopyingTo`).

I know that I could keep taking lines using the same reader and sequentially append them to the text file I'm writing, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way?

**EDIT:**

I found a StreamReader constructor which leaves the underlying stream open when it is disposed, so I tried this, hoping that the reader would set the stream's position as it's being disposed:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("c:\\test\\testinput.txt"))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 
        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true, 
        bufferSize: 1 << 12, 
        leaveOpen: true))
    {
        var numColumns = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
        while (numColumns-- > 0)
        {
            var colDescription = reader.ReadLine();
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    // Write remaining contents to another file
    using (var destination = File.OpenWrite("c:\\test\\testoutput.txt"))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(destination);
        destination.Flush();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't.  Why would this constructor be exposed if it doesn't leave the stream in an intuitive state/position?

Comment: It is as "greedy" as it needs to be, it uses an internal buffer to deal with having to look ahead in the base stream so it can properly detect a BOM, line endings and multi-byte text encoding.  You cannot assume that the Position property is ever meaningful when you deal with text files.

Comment: What is the contents of `colDescription` after `ReadLine()`? Place a counter inside the while loop to see how many times you really are looping. Maybe you are reading the whole file in the loop.

Comment: @KeithPayne: The initial `ReadLine` is getting the correct number; the loop is executing the correct number of times.  The `colDescriptions` are coming in correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there's a cleaner way. Use [ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the remaining data, and then write it to a new file. For example:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("c:\\test\\testinput.txt"))
{
    var numColumns = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
    while (numColumns-- > 0)
    {
        var colDescription = reader.ReadLine();
        // do stuff
    }

    // write everything else to another file.
    File.WriteAllText("c:\\test\\testoutput.txt", reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

### Edit after comment

If you want to read the text and upload it to a stream, you could replace the `File.WriteAllText` with code that reads the remaining text, writes it to a `StreamWriter` backed by a `MemoryStream`, and then sends the contents of that `MemoryStream`. Something like:

```
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memStream))
        {
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            writer.Flush();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            blob.UploadFromStream(memStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apologies. This perfectly answers the question as it was originally posed, but I have additional requirements (see edit).  +1

Comment: I suppose I could punch the remaining content to a temporary file as in this answer, then get a reading stream from _it_ to upload to a blob, but this seems somehow unnecessary.

Comment: Looks good, a few questions: (1) Would a StringWriter (with StringBuilder underneath) work better? (2) Is there an alternative that doesn't require the entire remaining contents to be read into memory?  This is why my mind went to trying to work with a stream directly in the first place.

Comment: @CSJ: I don't see how `StringWriter` would help. You'd end up with a `StringBuilder` with the text in memory, but `StringBuilder` isn't a stream. There is a way you could do it with a separate thread and my [ProducerConsumerStream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852) class, but that's probably more involved than you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should never access the underlying stream of a `StreamReader`.  Trying to use both is going to have an undefined behavior.

What's going on here is that the reader is buffering the data from the underlying stream.  It doesn't read each byte exactly when you request it, because that's often going to be very inefficient.  Instead it will grab chunks, put them in a buffer, and then provide you with data from that buffer, grabbing a new chunk when it needs to.

You should continue to use the `StreamReader` throughout the remainder of that block, instead of using `stream`.  To minimize the memory footprint of the program, the most effective way of doing this would be to read the next line from the reader in a loop until it his the end of the file, writing each line to the output stream as you go.

Also note that you don't need to be disposing of both the stream reader and the underlying stream.  The stream reader will dispose of the underlying stream itself, so you can simply adjust your header to:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(
    File.OpenRead("c:\\test\\testinput.txt")))
```

Comment: Same two comments I had for @Jim's answer: it's correct as originally posed but I need a stream to work with so that I can upload the remaining content somewhere remote.  If I read into your answer a bit more, I shouldn't try to work with the reader and the stream simultaneously?  +1

Comment: @CSJ You can use a `StringStream` to create a stream from the remaining string content.  If that won't be able to all fit into memory, then Jim's suggestion of a temp file would be an option.

Comment: `StringStream`? There's `StringWriter` and `StringReader`, but neither of those is a stream. At least, they aren't derived from the `Stream` class.

Comment: @JimMischel Right, I mean `StringReader`.  It's simple enough to convert a `TextReader` to a `Steam`, but yes, I there is that extra step.